# mq_open() with O_CREAT fails while open() with O_CREAT was successful

Tags: linux, posix, yocto

I writing some test codes compiling with x86_64-pokysdk-linux (yocto)

```
// return -1
m_mqueue_id = mq_open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);

// return 3
openfile_id = open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
```

I have no idea why mq_open fails even i gave O_CREAT option.

Is there any articles or solutions about similar situation?

EDIT : 
I looked up mq_overview(7) and I realize that I wasn't fully understanding about
message queue itself. changed its path to /dev/mqueue/~~ and problem solved.

```
On Linux, message queues are created in a virtual filesystem.  (Other
       implementations may also provide such a feature, but the details are
       likely to differ.)  This filesystem can be mounted (by the superuser)
       using the following commands:

           # mkdir /dev/mqueue
           # mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
```

Comment: You're not telling what `path` is. It can't be anything, go read the mq_overview(7) manpage.

Comment: what is the value of errno?

Comment: errno is ENONET. no such file or directory and the path is "/home/work/my_app/data/Mqueue"

Comment: I solved this problem with your advise. Thank you for your comment. mosvy